# Dom manipulation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I wrote the below code to remove an element with class rc-anchor-pt (if it is present in the DOM) after 5 seconds,

```
checkContainer();

counter = 1;
function checkContainer () {

    alert("checkContainer");
    $('.rc-anchor-pt').remove();
    $('.rc-anchor-logo-portrait').append('<a href=\"http://www.un.org/en/aboutun/privacy/\" target=\"_blank\">Privacy &amp; Terms</a>');
      if($('.rc-anchor-pt').is(':visible')){ //if the container is visible on the page
          var privacy = $('.rc-anchor-pt').find('a');

              } else {
          if (counter === 1)
         {
            setTimeout(checkContainer, 5000); //wait 50000 ms, then try again
            counter++;
         }
      }
 }
```

But the below line is not removing the element from the DOM. Can you please tell me what is the reason. Thanks in advance.I am running inside document.ready only The element is present in the page –

```
$('.rc-anchor-pt').remove();
```

Comment: Does `.rc-anchor-pt` exists in your HTML?

Comment: use $( document ).ready() to run the function instead of wait 5 seconds

Comment: if waiting 5 seconds doesn't work neither will waiting on document ready. the selector is likely wrong.

Comment: Just a note: your text says 5 seconds, your code says 4 seconds, and your comment says 40 seconds.

Comment: Your code doesn't logically make sense. You are removing an element, and then... checking if it is visible...

Comment: Kevin, I had to do this because the element appears in the page after 5 seconds

Comment: Deleted my answer as it's not answering your question, but `checkContainer` is getting hoisted above your counter declaration, so your `if (counter === 1)` condition will never be true.

Comment: @krishmandava what makes it appear? and why do you need to remove it? Surely there's some callback you can use, or some modification you can make to the code that's making it appear.

Comment: @Kevin It is the privacy and terms element in the recaptcha. I need to replace it with my own link

Comment: then yeah there's likely a better way. If you're doing something against the TOS already (not saying it is, but if it wasn't, surely there'd be a better way to do it) you might aswell just edit the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with your code. You have stated in your question that you wish to remove an element from the DOM after 5 seconds...You should be able to accomplish that with the following code:

```
$('.rc-anchor-logo-portrait').append('<br><a href=\"http://www.un.org/en/aboutun/privacy/\" target=\"_blank\">Privacy &amp; Terms</a>');  

setTimeout(function(){
     $('.rc-anchor-pt').remove();
}, 5000);
```

The way you have your code laid out, the `rc-anchor-pt` class will **never** be visible. It would really have no purpose then. If you want the `append` function to run after 5 seconds as well, just put it in the setTimeout function.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1399u65t/3/